# Itext7 - vertical aligment PdfFormField

Tags: java, itext7

Is there a way to edit vertica aligment of the text written in a PdfFormField.
The default seems to be center, I need a bottom.

With normal setValue the text is written at the center. I tried with rectangle/canvas but did not work (here the code)

```
PdfPage page = form.getField(key).getWidgets().get(0).getPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
PdfArray position = formFields.get(key).getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
double x = position.getAsNumber(0).getValue();
        double y = position.getAsNumber(1).getValue();
        double xWidth = position.getAsNumber(2).getValue();
        double yWidth = position.getAsNumber(3).getValue();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((float) x, (float) y, (float) xWidth, (float) yWidth);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, rectangle);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(valore);
        paragraph.setFont(font);
        paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        canvas.add(paragraph);
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard way to request different vertical alignments. You can always create custom appearances, though.

Comment: HOw can I override the appearance of an acroField